# How to do validation of user i.e whether the user with same email stored in the database or not in django?

Tags: django, django-models, django-views

I am having users model and user registration form and the user model is not the custom model so now I want to validate the user email in the database before registering if the same email present it should give an error message
My users model models.py

```
class users(models.Model):
    email=models.CharField(max_length=50,default='0000000')
    password=models.CharField(max_length=50,default='0000000')
    room = models.ForeignKey(rooms,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    goal = models.ManyToManyField(goals)
    style = models.ManyToManyField(designs)
    furn = models.ForeignKey(furniture,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

My views for registration:

```
def user_register(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        username=request.POST["username"]
        email = request.POST['email']
        password = request.POST['password']
        room = request.POST['room']
        g=goal=request.POST['goal']
        g = g.split(',')
        s=style=request.POST['style']
        s=s.split(',')
        furn=request.POST['furn']
        user = users(password=password,email=email)
        user.room=rooms.objects.get(pk=room)
        goal = goals.objects.filter(pk__in=g)
        style = designs.objects.filter(pk__in=s)
        request.encoding = 'koi8-r'
        user.furn = furniture.objects.get(pk=furn)
        user.save()
        user.goal.add(*goal)
        user.style.add(*style)
        return render(request,'register.html')
```

Comment: I would strongly advice to make the `email` unique, then it is validated in a `ModelForm`, and furthermore often enforced at the database side as well.

Answer (score 0):

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import User


if User.objects.filter(email=email).exists():
      messages.error(request, 'That email is being used')
      return redirect('register')
    else:
```

Comment: @ bmons where should I write this in views

Comment: @ bmons my model name is users

Comment: this call you can make after the post data, a similar approach you can make for username also

Comment: I want to validate and username exists or not and also pwd for 8 characters please say how this will be done in views

Answer (score 0):

I would strongly advise to make the `email` *unique*, then it is validated in a `ModelForm`, and furthermore often enforced at the database side as well. You can do so by setting the [**`unique=True`** parameter [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#unique).

You can implement this with:

```
class User(models.Model):
    email = models.CharField(max_length=50, unique=True)
    password = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    room = models.ForeignKey(rooms,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    goal = models.ManyToManyField(goals)
    style = models.ManyToManyField(designs)
    furn = models.ForeignKey(furniture,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

For validation purposes, you probably better use a [**`ModelForm`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/forms/modelforms/). This can render the form accordingly, validate data, and furthermore remove a lot of boilerplate code.

Furthermore you should *not* store passwords in a raw format: you should *hash* the passwords first. It might be better to take a look at the [*Extend the `User` model section* of the Django documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/auth/customizing/#extending-the-existing-user-model) and still use the *existing* `User` model, but for example with a complementary model (like `Profile`), to store the rest of the data.

Comment: @ willem then for username If I need to validate please say

Comment: @G.Lakshmi: please don't do this yourself: I strongly advise to take a look at the section on extending the user model: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/auth/customizing/#extending-the-existing-user-model

Comment: @ willem Okay sure and also after regsitartion I tried getting a success message it is not coming can you say how